# How to display cache data in list view when user is not connected to the internet in Android App

Tags: android, html, caching, jsoup, storage

I am am trying to access a cached file that is stored in the app's internal storage. The app works like this, when the user is connected on the internet I fetch the HTML data on the fly and display the content/strings in my list view and then I store the HTML data in the phone's cache. What I want is to be able to access this data when the user has no internet connection. Hopefully this makes sense. Storing the data looks to be working fine, but accessing it as a HTML file seems to be challenging so I can read it and extract certain elements/tags and assign it to an adapter on the post execute method. I've been looking everywhere for code samples but I can't seem to find any. I am relatively new to this and would appreciate any help. Thank you…

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //this try block fetches the HTML data and stores in into the CollegeValuesHTMLDOCMENT String. I then parse this
    //string onto the saveCollegeValuesHTMLTagsList(CollegeValuesHTMLDocument); method below.. so i can use it
    //to access the following when i need it for when i am not connected to the web... 
    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SchoolValuesUrl);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        CollegeValuesHTMLDocument = "";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            CollegeValuesHTMLDocument += line + "\n";
        }

        //connects to the url
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(SchoolValuesUrl).get();
        //finds the following tags in the url "li" and "h3"
        Elements liTags = document.select("li");
        Elements headingTags = document.getElementsByTag("h3");
        Elements pTags = document.getElementsByTag("p");

        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the li tags in the document
        liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element item : liTags) {
            liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
        }

        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the h3 tags in the document
        headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element item : headingTags) {
            headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
        }

        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the p tags in the document
        pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element item : pTags) {
            pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
        }

        //this method takes all HTML tags and stores it into the Internal Cache Storage of the Phone...
        //when passing the CollegeValuesHTMLDocument List variable
        saveCollegeValuesHTMLTagsList(CollegeValuesHTMLDocument);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your code. Please take a look at it. After that, please provide your exact problem. Your question is very vague.

Comment: hmmm hopefully this makes sense… ah trying to check internet connection of phone and if connected then connect to the URL and if not connected then see if there is a cache file to parse instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv answered my own question… so no need to post anything unless you think its going to be a easier solution.. Cheers Charlie

```
List<String> liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc, headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc, pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc;
        Document document;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setContentView(R.layout.listview_xml);

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GridViewMainMenuLayout.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Oats School Values");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();




        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        if (     connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                 connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {


                        try {

                                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SchoolValuesUrl);
                                    HttpResponse response;
                                    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

                                    CollegeValuesHTMLDocument = "";

                                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()
                                        )
                                      );

                                    String line = null;
                                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                                        CollegeValuesHTMLDocument += line + "\n";

                                        //this method takes all HTML tags and stores it into the Internal Cache Storage of the Phone...
                                        //when passing the CollegeValuesHTMLDocument List variable
                                        saveCollegeValuesHTMLTagsList(CollegeValuesHTMLDocument);

                                    }


                            //connects to the url
                            document = Jsoup.connect(SchoolValuesUrl).get();

                            //finds the following tags in the url "li" and "h3"
                            Elements liTags = document.select("li");
                            Elements headingTags = document.getElementsByTag("h3");
                            Elements pTags = document.getElementsByTag("p");


                            //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the li tags in the document
                            liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (Element item : liTags) {
                                liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                            }

                            //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the h3 tags in the document
                            headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (Element item : headingTags) {
                                headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                            }

                            //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the p tags in the document
                            pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (Element item : pTags) {
                                pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }   

        } else if ( 

                  connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {

                //connects to the url
                    try {

                        File folder = getCacheDir();
                        File ValuesHtmlDoc = new File(folder, "OatsValues.html");                           
                        document = Jsoup.parse(ValuesHtmlDoc, "UTF-8");



                        //finds the following tags in the url "li" and "h3"
                        Elements liTags = document.select("li");
                        Elements headingTags = document.getElementsByTag("h3");
                        Elements pTags = document.getElementsByTag("p");


                        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the li tags in the document
                        liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (Element item : liTags) {
                            liCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                        }

                        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the h3 tags in the document
                        headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (Element item : headingTags) {
                            headingCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                        }

                        //creating an list of items to store an array list of strings for all the p tags in the document
                        pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (Element item : pTags) {
                            pCollegeValuesTagsInHtmlDoc.add(item.text());
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   




        }
            return null;    
        }
```